# Kivy keeps coming up blank

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to learn kivy and have two files open my main python file and a kv file for styling, everytime I run the python file the resulting window always comes up blank. I am running it using `python main.py` on windows 10.

**main.py**

```
import kivy 
kivy.require('1.9.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class CustomLabel(Label):
    pass

class App(App):
    def build(self):
        return CustomLabel()

app = App()
app.run()
```

**kivy.kv**

```
<CustomLab@Label>:
    font_size: 32

<CustomLabel>:
    CustomLab:
        text: "Hello World"
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to edit your post and comment but I can't.

You should not name your main class as "App" instead you can name it like "TestApp".

Like this:

```
class TestApp(App):
```

Also your kivy file's name should be a lowercase of your "TestApp" without the word "App" on it.

Like this:

```
test.kv
```

Inside your kivy file, you misspelled the class "CustomLabel" as "CustomLab".

To declare a class inside a kivy file, you must use a "<" and ">".

Like this:

```
<CustomLabel>:
```

I changed your code and it looked like this:

This is your main.py:

```
import kivy
kivy.require("1.9.0")

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class CustomLabel(Label):
    pass

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return CustomLabel()

app = TestApp()
app.run()
```

This is your test.kv:

```
<CustomLabel>:
    text: "Hello World"
    font_size: 32
```

I hope this will work.